# QT: qmake not recognising 3dcore, 3drender

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt5, qmake

I am using `qmake` to compile my `QT` project. In my `.pro` file I have a line:

```
QT += 3dcore 3drender 3dinput 3dextras
```

When executing `qmake myprofile.pro` I get the error:

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: 3dcore 3drender 3dinput 3dextras
```

I am using `Ubuntu17` and have `QT5` installed. How can I get it to work with `qmake`? I am including libraries like `<Qt3DCore>` in my code so I require these modules as suggested [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-index.html).

Comment: Check if your Kit is pointing to a wrong version of Qt. Maybe this [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/86166/3d-modules-not-found/13) can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

3dcore introduced in Qt 5.7, ubuntu 17 had only 5.6 by default. If you have such problems, you need to update library.